# Handle the onChange event on a Select element in React

Tags: reactjs

when I select an option I want to get data of that selectedoptions and return them into another text input

here is my code

```
     <CFormSelect 
       aria-label="Default select example" 
       size='lg'
       name='product'
       id='product'
       value={selectProduct}
       onChange={handleChangle}
       >
      **<option > -- Choose Product --</option>
      {products.map((product) =>{
         return  <option key={product._id} value={product._id} >{product.designation}</option>
      })}**
     
     
    </CFormSelect>
    <CRow>
    <CCol className='col-sm-3'>
    <CFormLabel htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Qty in Stock </CFormLabel>
      <CFormInput 
        type="text" 
        size="lg"
        name='qteInStock'
        id='qteInStock'
        value={qteInStock}
        placeholder="Quantite" 
        aria-label="lg"
        onChange={(e) => setQteInStock(e.target.value)}
        disabled
        />
    </CCol>
    <CCol className='col-sm-3'>
    <CFormLabel htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Quantity </CFormLabel>
      <CFormInput 
        type="text" 
        size="lg"
        name='quantity'
        id='quantity'
        value={quantity}
        placeholder="Quantite" 
        aria-label="lg"
        onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
        /> 
    </CCol>
```

here is my onchange function

const handleChangle = (e) =>{

}

I don't know what to put inside to change the two input,i want to get back the product quantity and the product price...
am stuck since yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try to understand what you want to do, is it something like that ?

- User select the product via the
- Once selected, user can see the quantity in stock
- Once selected, user can chose an amount for quantity desired
- Total price is automatically print, sync with quantity desired.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-l8uqbk?file=App.tsx

I'm available if you have any questions, or need some help, can MP me.

Comment: Hey @Eric are you there?